# Is the mapping class group of a high distance general Heegaard splitting finitely generated?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are two handlebodies. If $\partial H_{1}$ and $\partial H_{2}$ are homeomorphic, then $H_{1}\cup_{f} H_{2}$ is a Heegaard splitting. To a general Heegaard splitting, one of $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ is allowed to be a compression body. Then the maximal genus boundary of $H_{1}$ is denoted by $\partial _{+}H_{1}$. Similar to $\partial_{+}H_{2}$. If $\partial _{+} H_{1}$ and  $\partial_{+}H_{2}$ are homeomorphic, then $H_{1}\cup_{\partial_{+}H_{1}}H_{2}$ is a general Heegaard splitting.

The mapping class group of $H_{1}\cup_{\partial_{+}H_{1}}H_{2}$  is the isotopy class of homeomorphisms of $\partial _{+}H_{1}$, which can be extended to be a homemorphism of $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$,.

If both $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are two handlebodies, it is the result of Namazi ["Big Heegaard distance implies finite mapping class group"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864107001897)that if the Heegaard distance (introduced by Hempel) is large enough then the mapping class group of it is finite. Later Johnson ["Mapping class groups of medium distance Heegaard splittings"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2010-138-12/S0002-9939-2010-10545-2/)extended this result and proved that if the Heegaard distance of it is at least 4, the mapping class  group of it is finite.

For a general Heegaard splitting,  may I ask the following question?

Question: If the Heegaard distance of it is large enough, is the mapping class group of it finitely generated?

Comment: Perhaps, I am misreading the question, but given the Johnson result, can your question be rephrased as "Let $H_1 \cup_f H_2$ be a Heegaard splitting of distance 1, 2, or 3.  Is the mapping class group of $H_1 \cup_f H_2$ finitely generated?"